# MySQL Create View

Tags: mysql

I tried to create a view for the table VIEW in information_schema.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Research as
select * from VIEWS;
```

But I'm getting an error like:

Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

What is the problem here? I can select other tables from the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should run ***mysql -u root -p*** in bash, not at the MySQL command-line. If you are in mysql, you can exit by typing ***exit***.

NOTE: use 'quit' to exit the mysql,then you will be in bash